# Allure Jenkins behave BDD report generating blank report

Tags: jenkins, allure, python-behave, html-reports-jenkins

[image][image] I have integrated my Acceptance testing Python Behave BDD with Jenkins and wanted to generate HTML report using Allure report. I am not seeing correct results on Allure report, as all are blank/null.

I am getting the below message from jenkins console however the folders are empty and report has no data.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Scs Testing>cd C:\checkouts\scs\test

C:\checkouts\scs\test>"behave --tags=@defrost_007 -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter  -o C:\checkouts\scs\test\TestResults  scs_acceptance_test/ "

1 feature passed, 0 failed, 1 skipped
1 scenario passed, 0 failed, 98 skipped
5 steps passed, 0 failed, 356 skipped, 0 undefined
Took 0m9.663s

C:\checkouts\scs\test>exit 0 
[Scs Testing] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\allure_2\allure-2.5.0\bin\allure.bat" generate -o "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Scs Testing\allure-report"

allure-results does not exists

Report successfully generated to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Scs Testing\allure-report

Allure report was successfully generated.

Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Finished: SUCCESS

Could you please give me some input?

First image - there is a zip file creating for each build however it is not able to extract it

Comment: I have added the answers
Please find the below link:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74943230/jenkins-allure-report-is-blank-for-python-behave-bdd/75170738#75170738>

Comment: I have added the answer Please find the below link:-
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74943230/jenkins-allure-report-is-blank-for-python-behave-bdd/75170738#75170738>

Answer (score 0):

I am myself a newbie in allure. My OS is Ubuntu. So my answer is based on what I have seen and observed on my OS.
But since this question is still open I will put in my two bits:

1. You report is empty because the report format is incorrect. What
   happens behind the scene is when you ask behave to use allure as a
   reporter tool, it creates a JSON file for the test output. In your
   case you can see the output on console. JSON should be generated on
   path:

   C:\checkouts\scs\test\TestResults scs_acceptance_test\

   Then when you give command allure generate, allure will read the
   JSON file generated in previous step and create a new folder called
   reports on path:

   C:\checkouts\scs\test\TestResults scs_acceptance_test\reports

   in which it generates and places the HTML code and serves the folder
   (reports) on a server that is starts.
2. Your command:

   ~allure.bat generate -o "C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Scs Testing\allure-report"

   is incorrect. The format is `allure [path-to-directory-where-you-have-your-json-file] -o [path-to-directory-where-you-want-to-generate-your-reports-directory]`

Comment: The command in your second point is auto generated by the system and seen in the jenkins console. We cannot correct the format unless you suggest a way to do so. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue for a while. I somehow figured out a solution.
My windows batch execution command is:
`pytest -s -v Test_practice_file.py --alluredir=allure-results`

[image]

After updating my allure reports folder n number of times, I updated the Post-build Actions for allure report as:
`-o ./allure-results`

[image]

In Allure Commandline, I have selected "From Maven Central">version 2.9.0 
Select the check box "Install automatically"

Save all the configurations and run your script