# Jenkins allure report is blank for python behave BDD

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bdd, allure, jenkins-cli

Hi I am very new to the python BDD and looking to generate a allure report in Jenkins .
However when I have integrated the allure in jenkins the report is coming blank.[image]

This is my build script:[image]

and this is post build configuration:
[image]

I have referred this link [Allure Jenkins behave BDD report generating blank report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759378/allure-jenkins-behave-bdd-report-generating-blank-report)
and other links as well;however no success.

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins - Dashboard->Manage Jenkins->Install "Allure Jenkins" and "ShiningPanda Plugin"

Then
Goto Manage Jenkins->Global Tool Configuration

Click on Allure Commandline Installations->enter Allure in Name
[image: Click on Allure Commandline Installations->enter Allure in Name]

In Configuration->in Build Steps->click on Custom Python Builder
[image: In Configuration->in Build Steps->click on Custom Python Builder]

In Home section->enter you python installation path->open cmd and enter->where python->enter
[image: In Home section->enter you python installation path->open cmd and enter->where python->enter]

then again add second Custom Python Builder and enter command->
behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure-results features/bankmanagerlogin.feature -D browser=chrome -D env=UAT
[image: then again add second Custom Python Builder and enter command-> behave -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o allure-results features/bankmanagerlogin.feature -D browser=chrome -D env=UAT]

Add allure report
[image: Add allure report]